# Hibernate Interceptor look up failing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We have a interceptor in hibernate to log data in Prometheus
This setup was working fine in Springboot 2 and Hibernate 5
recently we have upgarded to Springboot 3.2.4 and Hibernate 6.5.0
after the upgrade it started failing

My Interceptor class

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.EmptyStatementInspector;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class QueryInterceptor extends EmptyStatementInspector {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dbOperationsCounter")
    private MultiTaggedCounter dbOperationsCounter;

    @Override
    public String inspect(String sql) {
        try {
            // Extract table name and operation from the SQL statement
            String tableName = determineTableName(sql);
            String operation = determineOperation(sql);
            dbOperationsCounter.increment(tableName, operation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unable to push database operation counter metrics for sql: {}", sql, e);
        }

        return sql;
    }
```

My data Source Config Class

```
import com.authserver.jpa.interceptor.QueryInterceptor;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.TypeAnnotationsScanner;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.authserver",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "^com\\.authserver\\.postgres.*")
)
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "spring.datasource.default.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class MysqlDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "mysqlDataSourceProps")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.default")
    public DataSourceProperties cardDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.default.hikari")
    public DataSource cardDataSource(@Qualifier("mysqlDataSourceProps") DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource, QueryInterceptor queryInterceptor) {
        Set<String> entityClasses = scanEntities("com.authserver", "com.authserver.postgres");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManger = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManger.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManger.setPersistenceUnitName("default");
        entityManger.setJpaPropertyMap(getVendorProperties(queryInterceptor));
        entityManger.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManger.setPackagesToScan(entityClasses.toArray(new String[0]));

        return entityManger;
    }


    private Set<String> scanEntities(String includePackage, String excludePackage) {
        Reflections reflectionsInclude = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .forPackages(includePackage)
                .addScanners(new TypeAnnotationsScanner()));

        Set<Class<?>> includedEntities = reflectionsInclude.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class, true);

        Reflections reflectionsExclude = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .forPackages(excludePackage)
                .filterInputsBy(input-> input.startsWith(excludePackage))
                .addScanners(new TypeAnnotationsScanner()));

        Set<Class<?>> excludedEntities = reflectionsExclude.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class, true);

        includedEntities.removeAll(excludedEntities);

        return includedEntities.stream()
                .map(entity -> entity.getPackage().getName())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties(QueryInterceptor queryInterceptor) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", queryInterceptor);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
                                                              LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(mysqlEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }


}
```

```
Exception
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [com.armorcode.authserver.jpa.interceptor.QueryInterceptor@2960ae22] as strategy [org.hibernate.Interceptor]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.determineInterceptor(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:739)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.<init>(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.createSessionFactoryBuilder(DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 154 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.armorcode.authserver.jpa.interceptor.QueryInterceptor@2960ae22]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:150)
    ... 171 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.armorcode.authserver.jpa.interceptor.QueryInterceptor@2960ae22
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:123)
```

Tried making bean of QueryInterceptor that resulted in same error

Comment: `hibernate.session_factory.interceptor` setting is responsible for `org.hibernate.Interceptor`, you need to use `hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector` setting instead